# HTTP API Call to create consul watch & consul exec

Tags: consul, consul-template

Currently I am using consul watch & consul exec commands to create watches as well as to run some bash commands. I would like to use http api calls instead of commands to automate my system.

Is there http equivalents to do this work ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: checked this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/74417557/325320 it can be done in an undocumented way

Answer (score 0):

Under "Consul SDK":

https://www.consul.io/downloads_tools.html

there are bunches of libraries in various languages to talk to Consul.  I personally like Consulate, a Python API. you would be interested in the event call: http://consulate.readthedocs.io/en/stable/events.html  The consul exec and watches commands both use the event system.  I don't know the exact event(s) you would need to send to simulate an exec call, but I'm sure you can break out a watch, run an exec and see what it does.  Worse case you would have to look into the Consul source(written in go).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I looked at exec go command code and as you said it has calls to KV & event. It would be nice to have API calls directly instead of writing our own implementations :)

Comment: Yes, It would be nice. Perhaps you can post here the event calls for doing exec, to help the next person wanting to do this?

Comment: I just went through their code very briefly and didn't get a chance to create proper event calls yet, I will post it here once I find a way to do it.